# Is assoc behavior inconsistent?

Tags: java, clojure

`assoc` may throw IndexOutOfBoundsException when the index is, well, out of bounds, as in:

```
user=> (assoc [] 1 nil)
IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.PersistentVector.assocN(PersistentVector.java:137)
```

Why wouldn't it throw that same exception if I try to set the value at index 0?

```
user=> (assoc [] 0 nil)
[nil]
```

It seems to me that in both cases the index is out of bounds ...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assoc-in uses assoc to modify the element at the supplied key (index in your case). Assoc-in (and assoc) try to create what keys (or indexes) you require.

The special treatment for vectors is mentioned in the  assoc docstring:

> When applied to a vector, returns a new vector that
>       contains val at index. **Note - index must be <= (count vector)**.

**Update:** Just to clarify: The missing exception is consistent because while 0 is a valid index for a new element in an empty vector, 1 is not.

Comment: I see that the docstring clarifies that the behavior is not a bug but, is it inconsistent?

Comment: Why would it be inconsistent? The logic behind assoc and assoc-in is clearly that elements are created if they don't yet exist. In your first example, what element would you expect it to create at index 0 so that it can insert nil at index 1?

Comment: I totally agree that the function would not know what to insert at index 0 when requested to `assoc` at index 1. I'll mark the answer as the accepted answer (I also edited the question to refer to `assoc` instead of `assoc-in`). Thanks